# If I don’t profit in any way and have disclaimers, can I use Pokémon names in my app?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Suppose a developer creates a simplistic web-based educational game that uses Pokémon names, but not images. It has a similar battle style to the old Gameboy games, but all the images are original. If the dev were to publish it as a 100% free and open source educational application on web, android, and iOS, is it possible for the dev to run into copyright/trademark issues of any kind? Would it fall under fair use, and if not why?

If the developer will not profit off of the application in any way, does that help avoid legal problems?  Similarly, if the developer includes disclaimers about the Pokémon names would that help?

Are there other steps could such a developer take to avoid a lawsuit?

Suppose the developer simply posts the game to GitHub for potential employers to see. Could the developer get in trouble if someone pulls the code and publishes it elsewhere? If the developer is asked to take the game down, and does so, could the developer still face charges?

Comment: This is really asking what the law is for a particular situation. I will edit to make it more generic. It should not in my view be closed as asking for specific legal advice

Comment: There is no such thing as a "copyright disclaimer".

Comment: @pjc50  There can be such a thing as a "copyright disclaimer", for example when a work includes significant PD content, or is a derivative of a prior work. But it seems here that the OP meant statements that are in fact trademark disclaimers.

Comment: @DavidSiegel correct, that was poor wording on my part.

Comment: Copyright Disclaimers are actually *admittance that you had no right and should be prosecuted* for any IP holder worth their salt.

Comment: @Trish Not tue. Anyone may legally incorporate large amounts of PD text into a new work, and may include a disclaimer indicating what parts of the new work are free of copyright claims. Nor is a suit for copyright infringement properly described as "prosecution". The term "Copyright disclaimer" is also used for an attribution statement in connection with the use of a limited amount of content under a plausible claim of fair use or fair dealing.

Comment: So if a developer were to use their own images and names, but the images look similar to Pokémon, would it be wise to still include a disclaimer of some sort? If so, what would that look like? What if the images are part of a collection which is labeled as “a collection of fan art representing Pokémon”? Such as this one here: https://github.com/TheArtificial/pokemon-icons

Comment: @DavidSiegel ok, but the typical "X is by Y, I have no rights" can, if it is not fair use anyway, cut against the user.

Comment: @Teish Yes, in some cases. I more often see those for nominative use of trademarks.

Comment: @DavidSiegel they are used like candy in the wrong way by fanfiction writers, fangame makers and such, in ways where fair use and dealing is impossible.

Comment: Stefan If the images are similar enough that a disclaimer is wise, they might well be enough to make the game a derivative work and thus a copyright infringement. In such a case a disclaimer merely establishes that the imitation was knowing, and makes a suit measier to win. That is more or less the point that @trish was making, I think.

Comment: [I believe this is OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-KLAqyUg20)

Comment: Presumably: You: "I did not intend to infringe copyright" Prosecutor: "this guy knew he infringed copyright, he even said he was doing it unintentionally. Also by the way, since he knew this was copyright infringement and did it anyway, that means it was intentional." Judge: "case closed, defendant must pay the prosecution three million dollars"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making the game free makes very little if any difference to the position here. There are two kinds of IP issues that could possibly be involved: copyright and trademark.

Note: both copyright and trademark are civil, not criminal issues (except in very limited circumstances which do not apply to the situation described in the question). You will not "face charges" but might possibly be sued. If you are asked to take down such a game and comply, this might end the matter, but if an IP holder claimed that damages had occurred before the game was taken down a suite might possibly still be brought against the developer.

### Copyright

Names, like titles and other short phrases, cannot be protected by copyright. As long as no other text from anyone else, and no images are copied or imitated, copyright is not infringed. This means that there are no copyright issues. Game mechanics and rules cannot be copyrighted, although the words of game rules can be.

Therefore, *fair use* which is a strictly US copyright legal concept, is not involved here. Neither is *fair dealing*, a somewhat similar legal concept from the UK and some commonwealth and European countries.

### Trademark

Here is the main issue for this situation. The names of individual Pokémon   characters are probably (almost surely) protected as trademarks. That means you cannot use them to identify your game, or any other product or service, and you cannot use them to advertise or market your game. This is true even if the "selling price" is $0.

The use here does not seem to be nominative use, as you are not intending to refer to Pokémon or any of its variants. You are just reusing the names.

As long as you make it very clear that your game is not made by, nor in any way authorized or endorsed by the makers of Pokémon, this is probably not trademark infringement. But if the makers of Pokémon become aware of your game, they might well send you a cease and desist letter, and they might file a trademark infringement suit. Even if you were to win such a suit, as I think you might well do, it might be costly to defend.

Could you alter the names to ones you invent form yourself? That might save a lot of trouble and hassle. What is the value to you in reusing the well-known Pokémon names?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I originally was making the game for my nephew who is obsessed with Pokémon and wanted to play educational games with them. The characters in my game have a unique art style and don’t replicate any work by the makers of Pokémon. I was hoping to maintain the names so he could still recognize them, so I would prefer to use them. If I were to merely upload my source code to GitHub and not publish or host it anywhere, would that change the situation at all?

Comment: @Stefan One option: include a text config file which the user can alter that specifies the character names. For you nephew or other friends, set them to the Pokémon  names. For general release, set the defaults to something, anything else. Posting only to Github reduces the chance of legal action being taken, and probably reduces the amount of damages that could be claimed if it is. but it is still a public posting, so it does not eliminate the possibility

Comment: That’s a great idea! Thanks for all the advice!

Comment: The "non-profit" matter helps not as a legal defense, but an avoidence technique.   Lawsuits are expensive even if you are clearly going to win.   Legal fees are often included in the winnings regardless of final judgement of value.   Suing someone who has no money to pay you back and is not making money does mean Lawyers won't target you, and Non-profit and educational values are two oft claimed justifications of "Fair Use" in derivative works.  Not a garentee, but it helps lend to the case.  Personal use is fine too.

Comment: As someone who learned hexidecimal out of playing pokemon (using a gameshark to garentee a specific Pokemon appears in every wild encounter, the Pokemon was specified by its Pokedex number written in Hexidecimal notation) I applaud with using it as an educational tool.  It has a lot of in game and behind the scenes lore that cover a wide variety of subjects.  I'd even suggest looking into how to pitch the project to the Pokemon Company itself... The whole reason for the games was to encourage kids in wanting to explore the real world.

Comment: Some IP holders, such as Disney, have a reputation for pursuing even unprofitable defendants to deter other infringers. A holder might choose not to sue an infringer with little money, but that is a gamble. Fair use is not an issue in this case.

Comment: not so tiny correction: Pokemon are copyrighted. Each and every single visual design and every episode, every card art is registered...

Comment: @Trish yes the **images** are protected by copyright. But the question says the images will not be used. The same is true of the te4xtual descriptions. The **names** on their own cannot be protected by copyright.

Comment: Another alternative is to come up with close parody pokeymon names that are close enough to the names your nephew is use to, but different enough to not infringe on copyright.    That would still likely be enjoyable to your nephew, though it's more work on you to come up with that many parodies.

Comment: @dsollen The names are not protected by copyright in the first place.. Insofar as they are protected as trademarks, the use of "similar" marks is still trademark infringement. This strategy is not likely to reduce any actual liability that the dev might have.

Comment: @DavidSiegel wouldn't fair use come into play if they are explicit parodies of the names?

Comment: @dsollen No, it wouldn't. Even for copyright, parody is only a defense when it is used to comment on the original, not when it just reuses the original in a distorted pattern. But here copyright is not an issue at all. For trademarks there is NO parody defense if the similarity is great enough to suggest same source or authorization to some reasonable consumers. One may not trade on the good will or rep of another product without permission. "fair use" is only for copyright issues. For trademarks there is only *nominative use* which does not apply here. "parody" isn't a get-out-of-IP free card